# Read text file, split and use arrays to display elements in labels

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I am having trouble with my C# Windows Form Application. I have a text file in the format - LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,DateOfEnrolment,Gender as follows:

Bloggs,Joe,John,2015/01/04,M

There are 10 lines within the text file.

I want to read the text file in, split each line and put each element into an array. Each element will then be placed into its own label. There is a button called open to open the text file and then there is a button called first to show the elements of the first line in their individual labels. There is a button called previous to go to the previous line, next button to go to next line and last button to go to the last line, again showing the selected line's elements in the labels.vThe following code is what I have already but the btnFirst_Click is all showing red.

Please help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Assignment1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

public class SR
{
public string lastName;
public string firstName;
public string middleName;
public string date;
public string gender;
}
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List<SR> studentRecords = new List<SR>();
string file_name = (@"C:\Users\StudentRecords.txt");

StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(file_name);
objReader = new StreamReader(file_name);

int counter = 0;
string line;
while ((line = objReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
listBox.Items.Add(line);
counter++;
}

{
while (objReader.Peek() >= 0)
{
string str;
string[] strArray;
str = objReader.ReadLine();

strArray = str.Split(',');
SR currentSR = new SR();
currentSR.lastName = strArray[0];
currentSR.firstName = strArray[1];
currentSR.middleName = strArray[2];
currentSR.date = strArray[3];
currentSR.gender = strArray[4];

studentRecords.Add(currentSR);
}
}
objReader.Close();
}

private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
lblFN.Text = strArray[1];
lblMN.Text = strArray[2];
lblLN.Text = strArray[0];
lblDoE.Text = strArray[3];
lblGen.Text = strArray[4];
}
```

Comment: Well, sure. `strArray` is a local variable inside your `btnOpen_Click` method (and in fact it's even local to the body of your `while` loop). You can't read a local variable from another method. And even if you could, you get a new copy of that variable each time through the loop; which one do you want? Figure that out, and put it in a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: It's showing red because yo  created the strArray variable as local variable and not as class attribute.

Comment: Joe White... I want the elements of the array (last name, first name, middle name etc) to form an array. When the first button is clicked show the first line's elements in their own labels. Then, when the next button is clicked, go to the next line and so on. A previous button to go to the previous line etc and finally a last button to go to the last line of the text file again all showing each element in its own label

Answer (score 0):

Your `strArray` is defined in a loop within your `btnOpen_Click` method.  Therefore, trying to access it from `btnFirst_Click` will not work.  You need to move the declaration of `strArray` outside of the methods to make it accessible in both.

Try moving it to the top of your class definition, like so:

```
namespace Assignment1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string[] strArray;  // <---------- here is your array
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ...
```

Then you can access that array from both `btnOpen_Click` and `btnFirst_Click`.

Comment: It's coming up with the following error:

"Bad array declarator. To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type".

I don't understand

Comment: Oops, it should be like this: `private string[] strArray;`

Answer (score 0):

First, it's rare to really need to nest classes so..
(Use a full class name, no need to be lazy, and don't use public fields pretty much ever, use properties (capitalized)).

```
public class StudentRecord
{
  public string LastName { get; set;} 
  public string FirstName { get; set;}
  public string MiddleName { get; set;}
  public string Date { get; set;}
  public string Gender { get; set;}
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
  // ....
}
```

Secondly, avoid using arrays (IMHO):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  // initialize list to zero, we'll reset everytime
  // we load students.  Also a null list will
  // throw an error below the way I have it coded.
  private List<StudentRecord> _studentRecords = new List<StudentRecord>(0);
  // ..
}
```

Avoid actually putting logic in the `btnOpen_Click` method:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  LoadStudentRecords();
}
```

Easy way to read a file:

```
private void LoadStudentRecords()
{
  // reset the list to empty, so we don't always append to existing
  _studentRecords = new List<StudentRecord>();
  string file_name = (@"C:\Users\StudentRecords.txt");
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file_name).ToList();
  foreach(var line in lines)
  {
    var studentRecord = ParseStudentRecordLine(line);
    if (studentRecord != null)
    {
      _studentRecords.Add(studentRecord);
    }
  }
}
```

Separate logic into logic methods:

```
public StudentRecord ParseStudentRecordLine(string line)
{
  SR result = null;

  // error check line, don't want to blow up
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
  {
    var values = line.Split(',');
    // error values length, don't want to blow up
    if (values.Length == 5) // or > 4
    {
      var result = new StudentRecord();
      result.lastName = values [0];
      result.firstName = values [1];
      result.middleName = values [2];
      result.date = values [3];
      result.gender = values [4];
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Lastly assign them:

```
private void ShowStudent(StudentRecord studentRecord)
{
  // what if we haven't loaded student records
  // and someone tried to show one?
  if (studentRecord != null)
  {
    lblFN.Text = studentRecord.FirstName;
    lblMN.Text = studentRecord.MiddleName;
    lblLN.Text = studentRecord.LastName;
    lblDoE.Text = studentRecord.Date;
    lblGen.Text = studentRecord.Gender;

    _currentStudentRecordIndex = _studentRecords.IndexOf(studentRecord);
  }
  else
  {
    // Show error msg "No students to show, maybe load students first"
  }
}
```

> There is a button called previous to go to the previous line, next button to go to next line and last button to go to the last line,

So you want to keep an index of the current element.  Add your index to your form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private List<StudentRecord> _studentRecords = new List<StudentRecord>(0);
  private int _currentStudentRecordIndex = 0;
}
```

Make sure you reset the value to zero if you load or press first.

```
private void LoadStudentRecords()
{
  _currentStudentRecordIndex = 0;      
  _studentRecords = new List<StudentRecord>();
  // ....
```

Standard first/previous/next/last logic:
(can be done differently, just doing some Labda/Linq Fun for an example).

```
private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var firstStudent = _studentRecords.FirstOrDefault();

  ShowStudent(firstStudent);
}

private void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var count = _studentRecords.Count;
  if (count > 0)
  {
    var studentRecord = _studentRecords.ElementAt(count-1);

    ShowStudent(studentRecord );
  }      
}

private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var studentRecordIndex = _currentStudentRecordIndex - 1;

  if (studentRecordIndex > -1)
  {
    var studentRecord = _studentRecords.ElementAt(studentRecordIndex );

    ShowStudent(studentRecord );
  }      
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Should be able to do this based on previous logic
}
```

**notes**

This is far from perfect, but I hope it explains what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably doing an assignment for you, lol but this will get you the results that you are after:

```
class Program
{
    // Contains the elements of an line after it's been parsed.
    static string[] array;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Read the lines of a file into a list of strings. Iterate through each
        // line and create an array of elements by parsing (splitting) the line by a delimiter (eg. a comma).
        // Then display what's now contained within the array of strings.
        var lines = ReadFile("dummy.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            array = CreateArray(line);
            Display();
        }

        // Prevent the console window from closing.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Reads a file and returns an array of strings.
    static List<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();
        using (var file = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        return lines;
    }

    // Create an array of string elements from a comma delimited string.
    static string[] CreateArray(string line)
    {
        return line.Split(',');
    }

    // Display the results to the console window for demonstration.
    static void Display()
    {
        foreach (string item in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

**Where the sample contained with a text file is the following:**

```
Bloggs,Joe,John,2015/01/04,M
Jones,Janet,Gillian,2015/01/04,F
Jenfrey,Jill,April,2015/01/04,F
Drogger,Jeff,Jimmy,2015/01/04,M
```

**The results would be:**

```
Bloggs
Joe
John
2015/01/04
M

Jones
Janet
Gillian
2015/01/04
F

Jenfrey
Jill
April
2015/01/04
F

Drogger
Jeff
Jimmy
2015/01/04
M
```

Alternatively, based on your business requirements, you can use the following solution to generate a list of student record objects:

```
class Program
{
    static int _recordIndex;
    static List<StudentRecord> _studentRecords;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize a list of student records and set the record index to the index of the first record.
        _studentRecords = new List<StudentRecord>();
        _recordIndex = 0;

        // Read the lines of a file into a list of strings. Iterate through each
        // line and create a list of student records of elements by parsing (splitting) the line by a delimiter (eg. a comma).
        // Then display what's now contained within the list of records.
        var lines = ReadFile("dummy.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            _studentRecords.Add(CreateStudentResult(line)); 
        }

        Display();

        // Prevent the console window from closing.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Reads a file and returns an array of strings.
    static List<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();
        using (var file = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        return lines;
    }

    // Get the next student record in the list of records
    static StudentRecord GetNext()
    {
        // Check to see if there are any records, if not... don't bother running the rest of the method.
        if (_studentRecords.Count == 0)
            return null;

        // If we are on the index of the last record in the list, set the record index back to the first record. 
        if (_recordIndex == _studentRecords.Count - 1)
        {
            _recordIndex = 0;
        }
        // Otherwise, simply increment the record index by 1.
        else
        {
            _recordIndex++;
        }

        // Return the record at the the new index.
        return _studentRecords[_recordIndex];
    }

    static StudentRecord GetPrevious()
    {
        // Check to see if there are any records, if not... don't bother running the rest of the method.
        if (_studentRecords.Count == 0)
            return null;

        // If we are on the index of the first record in the list, set the record index to the last record. 
        if (_recordIndex == 0)
        {
            _recordIndex = _studentRecords.Count - 1;
        }
        // Otherwise, simply deincrement the record index by 1.
        else
        {
            _recordIndex--;
        }

        // Return the record at the the new index.
        return _studentRecords[_recordIndex];
    }

    // Create a StudentResult object containing the string elements from a comma delimited string.
    static StudentRecord CreateStudentResult(string line)
    {
        var parts = line.Split(',');
        return new StudentRecord(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]);
    }

    // Display the results to the console window for demonstration.
    static void Display()
    {
        // Display a list of all the records
        Console.WriteLine("Student records:\n----------------");
        foreach (var record in _studentRecords)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Display the first record in the list
        Console.WriteLine("First record is:\n----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(_studentRecords.First().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Display the last record in the list.
        Console.WriteLine("Last record is:\n----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(_studentRecords.Last().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Display the next record in the list
        Console.WriteLine("Next record is:\n----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(GetNext().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Display the last record in the list.
        Console.WriteLine("Previous record is:\n----------------");
        Console.WriteLine(GetPrevious().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // A record object used to store the elements of parsed string.  
    public class StudentRecord
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        public string Gender { get; set; }

        // Default constructor
        public StudentRecord()
        {
        }

        // Overloaded constructor that accepts the parts of a parsed or split string.
        public StudentRecord(string lastName, string firstName, string middleName, string date, string gender)
        {
            this.LastName = lastName;
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.MiddleName = middleName;
            this.Date = date;
            this.Gender = gender;
        }

        // Overrided ToString method which returns a string of property values.
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format(
                "Last name: {0}\nFirst name: {1}\nMiddle name: {2}\nDate {3}\nGender: {4}",
                this.LastName, this.FirstName, this.MiddleName, this.Date, this.Gender);
        }
    }
}
```

**The results of the above code would be the following:**

```
Student records:
----------------
Last name: Bloggs
First name: Joe
Middle name: John
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: M

Last name: Jones
First name: Janet
Middle name: Gillian
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: F

Last name: Jenfrey
First name: Jill
Middle name: April
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: F

Last name: Drogger
First name: Jeff
Middle name: Jimmy
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: M

First record is:
----------------
Last name: Bloggs
First name: Joe
Middle name: John
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: M

Last record is:
----------------
Last name: Drogger
First name: Jeff
Middle name: Jimmy
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: M

Next record is:
----------------
Last name: Jones
First name: Janet
Middle name: Gillian
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: F

Previous record is:
----------------
Last name: Bloggs
First name: Joe
Middle name: John
Date 2015/01/04
Gender: M
```